# Windows 8 -- Blank desktop after installing NVIDIA drivers

Tags: windows-8-preview

I just installed my mobile NVIDIA drivers, and ever since the usual flicker, my desktop goes blank.

I **can** start Task Manager and log off/log on, but **any** other window which I try to bring up automatically hides behind a blank screen. The animations are visible, but the window isn't. So I can't really know what I'm doing. (Alt-tab, etc. don't show the popups but not the windows.)

Anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that reinstalling Windows 8 and then using the *latest* drivers (which were around ~1-2 months newer) fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Use F8 to get the Option menu, choose "Troubleshoot"

[image]

.

Then choose "Advanced Options"

.
[image]

Then choose System Restore

.
[image]

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to mention -- I'd turned it off. lol. +1 anyway

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried booting in the Safe Mode by pressing F8 during the boot sequence? In safe mode you may be able to uninstall Nvidia display drivers

Comment: Safe mode in Windows 8? good joke.. :P does it even exist?

Comment: @Mehrdad: I believe safe mode does exist; after all, at some level you need to fix things when they break. That said, I don't think uninstalling the nVidia drivers is a reasonable solution; Win8 is pretty much unusable without graphics acceleration.

Comment: @Billy Oneal: It sure runs fine on my GMA.

Comment: @surfasb: Not all systems have GMAs. Recent GMA chipsets do hardware acceleration themselves. I can say that Win8 on my Dell Latitude E6500, which has only an nVidia Quadro NVS 160M, Win8 is basically unusable. Doubly so before the drivers got installed.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to uninstall any graphics drivers and use the Windows Update Nvidia drivers. There are  substantial changes to the Windows 8 graphics driver model that you **don't** want to install OEM drivers.

For more info, google the Windows 8 WDM.