# How can I set Windows Developer Preview resolution to 1920x1080 screen resolution

Tags: windows-8-preview, nvidia-geforce, flip

I have a new monitor which I'm sharing between two computers: a laptop with Windows 7 (**Windows 7** from now on) and a home assembled desktop with Windows 8 Developer Preview (**WinDev** from now on).

**Windows 7** recognizes the monitor resolution of 1920x1080, and many others. **Windows 8 Developer Preview** doesn't; the best resolution I get on that OS is 1600x1200.

**Windows 7** has:

- Mobile Intel 965 Express video
- Generic PnP Monitor as monitor #2

**Windows 8 Developer Preview** has:

- MSI Nvidia 9600GT with 1Gb RAM video
- Generic Non PnP Monitor

I'm using [Belkin Flip](http://www.belkin.com/flip/) USB to share the monitor between boxes

Comment: Did you install the drivers of the Nvidia card and the Flip device?

Comment: yes I did, in fact nVidia drivers were installed by the OS after installation but they were from nVidia.

Comment: The OS doesn't always provide the latest ones, you might want to check the version and download a newer one at Nvidia themselves.

Comment: This is not from MS, it's from nVidia, and it has the Tray Icon with the Update option from nVidia and it's updated.

Comment: Yes, it'll always be from Nvidia. But the driver version can differ a lot...

Comment: you know? you were right, kudos to you, I checked the installed driver version and it was 285.16 and I'm downloading now 285.62. Checking for updates does not appear to work. After installing I will comment the results

Comment: well.. it didn't work, latest driver did the same

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have a non-PnP monitor you might want to see how you can add a mode and force to use that mode, you can do this in the **Nvidia Control Panel** > **Change resolution** > **Customize**.

***Caution:*** Only do this if your monitor is known to support the resolution you need.

Comment: Hi Tom, I did this already and could change resolution to 1600x1024 instead of 1600x1200, which is good because the aspect ratio is better this way but it is not the optimal. When I selected 1920x1080 nothing happened, but when I select 1600x1200 or 1600x1024 resolution is changed immediately.

Comment: Moreover, my 'non-PhP monitor' is recognized as 'PnP Monitor' by Win7 in another machine that's at the other end of the Flip switch, so I think there's a problem with WinDev

Comment: @EugenioMiró: So, if I got that right it does list the resolution but it doesn't want to load it? Did you click the accept button in the bottom right corner?

Comment: Yes I did, several times, and after that, when I click 1600x1024, just clicking the option the resolution changes.

Answer (score 0):

There's a suggestion [here](https://superuser.com/a/335725/3560) to uninstall the NVidia drivers and to allow Windows Update to install the NVidia drivers, as they are substantially different for Windows 8.